# Executing A .jar File In Deepin

Tags: java, deepin

I recently received a Minecraft 1.5.2.jar file and downloaded it as seen in the picture below.
[image: Minecraft 1.5.2]

I used the command `java -jar minecraft.jar` but it returns the error
[image]

Can anyone help me out with launching this file, please? If anyone can give me the next steps to launch this file, it will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to do this in the Downloads directory, run `cd Downloads` first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you moved cwd? Try `cd ~/Downloads` before use command.